# SSIS cannot connect to SSMS using SQL Server Authentication

Tags: sql-server, authentication, ssis

I'm trying to set up a connection to `SSMS` from `SSIS` project I'm working on with `SQL Server Authentication`.

I set up a cube_user login and gave it permission to my database `transactions`
Here is how I set up my cube_user:
Login Name, password. I also chose the default DB below to transactions, the appropriate DB.

[image]

Then in `User Mapping` tab, I gave user owner permissions and I checked in the appropriate DB

[image]

Having done all that, it seems like it should work. I then started an SSIS project and tried to connect to it like this:

[image]

As you can the drop down that is supposed to display databases, is blank. However, If i tried to connect to it using Windows Authentication, I am able to see all DBs....

[image]

Is there something wrong I'm doing. Can you not connect to SSMS using SQL Server Authentication?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check the following things:

- In properties of cube_user - that it has at least `guest` rights on the RDBMS (SQL Server itself). User rights on specific DB will not give the permission to connect to SQL Server. The properties are in SSMS - Security\Logins - specific Login properties - Server Roles. See example below
  [image]
- On the third screenshot where you specify user name and password - specify those of `cube_user`, not `admin`.

The reason why you see list of DBs with Windows Auth - you do it under your account which presumably has DBA user rights on the SQL Server.

Comment: Thanks a bunch I'll come back to this later tonight when I test this at home. Now that I look at it, it does say admin, but I did try to do it with cube_user, i was just trying to take screenshots quickly without thinking too much about it. I think I'm missing exactly what you showed in your screenshot